# Global css for Angular 8 library

Tags: angular

How to add global css for angular 8 library so that style gets applied to each and every component inside the library, i dont have main wrapper container the library displays the different page for different route

Comment: How your folder structure looks like, can you please add?

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the angular project with Angular CLI there will be  **styles.scss** file where you can add any styles you want applied globally.

Comment: he meant global scss for the angular lib not angular project

Answer (score 1):

If you have style.scss file so where you can apply globally CSS. it'll affected to all your CSS libraries and classes

Answer (score -2):

You can create style.scss file and include that in angular.json `"styles": [ "src/styles.scss" ],` which will be affected globally